# Why is Seth said to be in likeness and image of his father in Genesis 5:3?

Tags: genesis, adam, niv, cain

Genesis 5:3 NIV

3 When Adam had lived 130 years, he had a son in his own likeness, in his own image; and he named him Seth.

Adam had other sons prior to Seth who were not said to be in his likeness and image

Genesis 4:4 NIV

4 Adam[a] made love to his wife Eve, and she became pregnant and gave birth to Cain.[b] She said, “With the help of the Lord I have brought forth[c] a man.” 2 Later she gave birth to his brother Abel.

Was there something special about Seth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that all men are made in God’s image even after the fall.

> ““Whoever sheds the blood of man, by man shall his blood be shed, for God made man in his own image.”
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭9:6‬

The idea of being in the ‘image of’ denotes being the representative of.

[In the image of](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/49831/image-vs-likeness-in-genesis-126/49835#49835) please see my response to this question

The fact that Seth was the image bearer of Adam and not Cain and not the deceased Abel speaks to the fact that Seth is now the representative of Adam, he carries the lineage as head of the family. This is reinforced by the alephtav or the et (the word)

Please refer to my answer to this question [the alephtav as the lineage marker](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/44760/in-genesis-2112-what-does-through-isaac-your-offspring-will-be-reckoned-mea/44761#44761)

Cain was not the image bearer of Adam because he was a murderer and abandoned his father’s side. Abel was deceased without an heir to carry the lineage further and Seth was qualified because he had a descendant and was a replacement of Abel who was a righteous progeny of Adam

> “And Adam knew his wife again, and she bore a son and called his name Seth, for she said, “God has appointed for me **another offspring instead of Abel**, for Cain killed him.” To **Seth also a son was born**, and he called his name Enosh. At that time people began to call upon the name of the Lord.”
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭4:25-26‬ ‭

This was all important because a promise was made that from the seed of the woman a savior would eventually be born who would represent his forefather Adam and restore that which was lost in Eden

> “Thus it is written, “The first man Adam became a living being”; the last Adam became a life-giving spirit.”
> ‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭15:45‬ ‭

Answer (score 0):

The biblical book of Genesis has a strong chronological backbone, going up to Abraham (the book's first major character, the other two being Jacob and Joseph), upon which further stories (such as the two Creation Accounts, the Fall of Man, Cain and Abel, the Tower of Babel, the Fall of Angels, Noah's Flood, etc.) are added, as muscles unto a sustaining skeleton. These inserted episodes, however, do not meaningfully affect the flow of the overarching narrative upon which they are grafted; allow me to demonstrate:

> <sup>**Genesis** <sup>**1:1**</sup> ¶In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth. <sup>**1:26**</sup> ¶And God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness: and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth. <sup>**1:27**</sup> So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them. <sup>**1:28**</sup> And God blessed them, and God said unto them, Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth, and subdue it: and have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over every living thing that moveth upon the earth. <sup>**5:3**</sup> And Adam [Man] lived an hundred and thirty years, and begat a son in his own likeness, after his image; and called his name Seth: <sup>**5:5**</sup> And all the days that Adam lived were nine hundred and thirty years: and he died. <sup>**5:6**</sup> ¶And Seth lived an hundred and five years, and begat Enos: <sup>**5:8**</sup> And all the days of Seth were nine hundred and twelve years: and he died. <sup>**5:9**</sup> And Enos lived ninety years, and begat Cainan: <sup>**5:11**</sup> And all the days of Enos were nine hundred and five years: and he died. <sup>**5:12**</sup> And Cainan lived seventy years, and begat Mahalaleel: <sup>**5:14**</sup> And all the days of Cainan were nine hundred and ten years: and he died. <sup>**5:15**</sup> And Mahalaleel lived sixty and five years, and begat Jared: <sup>**5:17**</sup> And all the days of Mahalaleel were eight hundred ninety and five years: and he died. <sup>**5:18**</sup> And Jared lived an hundred sixty and two years, and he begat Enoch: <sup>**5:20**</sup> And all the days of Jared were nine hundred sixty and two years: and he died. <sup>**5:21**</sup> ¶And Enoch lived sixty and five years, and begat Methuselah: <sup>**5:23**</sup> And all the days of Enoch were three hundred sixty and five years: <sup>**5:24**</sup> And Enoch walked with God: and he was not; for God took him. <sup>**5:25**</sup> ¶And Methuselah lived an hundred eighty and seven years, and begat Lamech: <sup>**5:27**</sup> And all the days of Methuselah were nine hundred sixty and nine years: and he died. <sup>**5:28**</sup> ¶And Lamech lived an hundred eighty and two years, and begat a son: <sup>**5:29**</sup> And he called his name Noah, saying, This same shall comfort us concerning our work and toil of our hands, because of the ground which the LORD hath cursed. <sup>**5:31**</sup> And all the days of Lamech were seven hundred seventy and seven years: and he died. <sup>**5:32**</sup> And Noah was five hundred years old: and Noah begat Shem, Ham, and Japheth. <sup>**7:6**</sup> And Noah was six hundred years old when the flood of waters was upon the earth. <sup>**9:29**</sup> And all the days of Noah were nine hundred and fifty years: and he died. <sup>**11:10**</sup> ¶Shem was an hundred years old, and begat Arphaxad two years after the flood: <sup>**11:11**</sup> And Shem lived after he begat Arphaxad five hundred years. <sup>**11:12**</sup> And Arphaxad lived five and thirty years, and begat Salah: <sup>**11:13**</sup> And Arphaxad lived after he begat Salah four hundred and three years. <sup>**11:14**</sup> And Salah lived thirty years, and begat Eber: <sup>**11:15**</sup> And Salah lived after he begat Eber four hundred and three years. <sup>**11:16**</sup> And Eber lived four and thirty years, and begat Peleg: <sup>**11:17**</sup> And Eber lived after he begat Peleg four hundred and thirty years. <sup>**11:18**</sup> And Peleg lived thirty years, and begat Reu: <sup>**11:19**</sup> And Peleg lived after he begat Reu two hundred and nine years. <sup>**11:20**</sup> And Reu lived two and thirty years, and begat Serug: <sup>**11:21**</sup> And Reu lived after he begat Serug two hundred and seven years. <sup>**11:22**</sup> And Serug lived thirty years, and begat Nahor: <sup>**11:23**</sup> And Serug lived after he begat Nahor two hundred years. <sup>**11:24**</sup> And Nahor lived nine and twenty years, and begat Terah: <sup>**11:25**</sup> And Nahor lived after he begat Terah an hundred and nineteen years. <sup>**11:26**</sup> And Terah lived seventy years, and begat Abram, Nahor, and Haran. <sup>**11:27**</sup> ¶And Haran begat Lot. <sup>**11:28**</sup> And Haran died before his father Terah in the land of his nativity, in Ur of the Chaldees. <sup>**11:29**</sup> And Abram and Nahor took them wives: the name of Abram's wife was Sarai; and the name of Nahor's wife, Milcah, the daughter of Haran, the father of Milcah, and the father of Iscah. <sup>**11:30**</sup> But Sarai was barren; she had no child. <sup>**11:31**</sup> And Terah took Abram his son, and Lot the son of Haran his son's son, and Sarai his daughter in law, his son Abram's wife; and they went forth with them from Ur of the Chaldees, to go into the land of Canaan; and they came unto Haran, and dwelt there. <sup>**11:32**</sup> And the days of Terah were two hundred and five years: and Terah died in Haran.</sup>

Notice, then, that the explicit mention of Seth being created in man's (Adam's) image plays a vital role in tying together (the beginning of) this major underlying historical thread, whereas such a mention in the case of the interwoven Cain and Abel interlude would have proven completely unnecessary or superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

kain was not the son of adam and did not resemble adam..  from the garden there were two seeds and enmity put between them,   who? priovides the seed and who provides the egg??   that means there are two males and ONE mother of all living..  NOWHERE in nature does woman provide a seed..    what is superfecundation?  its a medical term..  and the begining of two species..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/45354)

Comment: This is not addressing the question. Also the Bible says the woman has seed (Genesis 3:15)